# Insert json array data from url into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to pass JSON data from a live url (power API) into a mysql database on a daily basis. Here's my code:

```
//read the json file contents
$jsondata = file_get_contents('http://ws.meteocontrol.de/api/sites/P9JWT/data/energygeneration?apiKey=xVQfZ7HaA9');

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

//get the solar power details
$date = $data['date'];
$data = $data['timestamp']['power'];

//insert into mysql table
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_power(date, data)
VALUES('$date', '$data')";
if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Please indicate the error in my code or how I can get this to work. I'm not a PHP developer, I'm mostly self-taught and still fairly new to PHP and JQuery. Any assistance to point out my error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: It may be useful to identify what the error message is that you are being presented with and what is currently happening when you run the PHP file.

Comment: You might want to start by taking a look at the actual data structure, e.g. via `echo '<pre>', var_export($data, true), '</pre>'`. $data woule be `$date = $data['chartData']['date'];` and there is no `timestamp` element in the data.

Comment: Your code references `timestamp` & `power` ~ these do not appear in the data returned from your api call. You do not make it clear what the problem is nor whether you need each pair from the data values entered into a new row in your db or whether it is the entire dataset

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I need to get each pair of data values entered into a new row in the database. The first part of the json is the timestamp and the second is the power generation: [
1457049600000,
-0.06
] 
I need to get the timestamp and power generation into a table with two columns, one for timestamp and one for power generation.

Comment: I need to get a table like this:
|___time__|___ power__|
|   06:00   |    0.01   |
|   06:05   |    0.01   |
|   06:10   |    0.01   |

Every day these two sets of data need to be entered into the mysql database to allow me to draw charts with it. Eventually, I will be drawing cumulative charts with monthly data, so every day needs to be saved into the database.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already got a more or less complete example using the [deprecated mysql_* functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), here is an example using [PDO](http://docs.php.net/PDO) and a [prepare statement + parameters](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

```
<?php
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents('...url...'), true, 5, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING ) ;
if ( !$data ) {
    die('something went wrong with the JSON data');
}
else if ( !isset($data['chartData']) || !isset($data['chartData']['date'], $data['chartData']['data']) || !is_array($data['chartData']['data']) ) {
    die('unexpected JSON format');
}
else {
    // connect to the database
    // see http://docs.php.net/pdo.construct
    // and http://docs.php.net/ref.pdo-mysql.connection
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
    // this will create a (temporary) table, that fits the INSERT statement for this example
    setup($pdo);

    // prepare a statement with two parameters
    // see http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO so_tbl_power (`gmtdate`, `data`) VALUES ( :pit, :measurement )');
    $stmt->bindParam(':pit', $pit);
    $stmt->bindParam(':measurement', $measurement);
    // when the statement is executed the values that are "in" $pit and $measurement at that moment will be used where the placeholders :pit and :measurement were placed in the statement. 

    $date = $data['chartData']['date']; // won't be using this ....
    foreach( $data['chartData']['data'] as $mp ) {
        // ? mp[1] <-> measurement reading failed?
        // skip those entries that do not have a value in $mp[1]
        // you might want to insert those anyway ....but I don't ;-)
        if ( !is_null($mp[1]) ) { 
            $mp[0] = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', substr($mp[0], 0, -3));
            // assign the values to the parameters bound to the statement
            list($pit, $measurement) = $mp;
            // execute the statement (with those parameters)
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }


    // now let's see what is in the table
    foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT id,`gmtdate`, `data` FROM so_tbl_power ORDER BY id', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ) {
        echo join(', ', $row), "\r\n";
    }
}


function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE so_tbl_power (
            id int auto_increment,
            `gmtdate` DateTime NOT NULL, 
            `data` Decimal(8,4),
            primary key(id),
            unique key(`gmtdate`)
        )
    ');
}
```

Converting the timestamp to a DateTime field in the database is only included to show you *how* to do it *if* you want to do it.

Comment: PDO for people who start learn php is not the easier way. He need to try mysqli for begin

Comment: Agreed. PDO is very intimidating . Can you assist with mysqli code?

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to be more intimidated by pdo than by msqli. This goes so far as to that we have questions here on stackoverflow with comments like `Oh...bind_param with an underscore, so it's mysqli, not pdo" on a regular basis because the code is so similar.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a go. How do I implement the code above? Should  /*connect to DB*/ $con=mysql_connect ...  /**/ be added at the top to point to the database before getting the json contents?

Comment: Btw: the code is an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). All you have to do is adjust the credentials (using an account that is allowed to create a temporary table) and it will run.

Comment: I changed the values and added the credentials $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', $user, $pass, array.

Comment: I get a fatal error with my credentials, despite ensuring they are correct: http://solafuturedisplay.co.za/php-test/

Comment: DId you also change the `dbname=test`part?

Comment: Yes, I changed 4 values: host, dbname, user & password.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mcpYM94Z , when you adjust the variables, this only complains about the pdo instance, not the mysql connection code?

Comment: My code work, to use mysqli simply change mysql to mysqli

Answer (score 1):

The json structure is

```
  {"chartData":

  {"prev":"2016-03-03",

  "next":null,

  "date":"2016-03-04",

  "type":"day",

  "data":[

  [1457135400000,null],[1457135700000,null]

  ....

  ]
```

In your code

```
  $data = $data['timestamp']['power'];
```

> In json file no `timestamp` and `power` fields

**I think you need that data** `"data":[[1457135400000,null],[1457135700000,null]]}}`

**When you need to do a loop** `foreach()`

```
   <?

   /*connect to DB*/
   $con=mysql_connect($bd_host, $bd_user, $bd_password); 
   /*control connection*/
   if(!con) {
   echo 'Error.'; 
   exit; 
   }
   /*select databese name*/
   mysql_select_db($bd_base, $con); 
   /*set encode to utf-8*/
   mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
   /**/

    $jsondata = file_get_contents('http://ws.meteocontrol.de/api/sites/P9JWT/data/energygeneration?apiKey=xVQfZ7HaA9');

    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $date=$data['chartData']['date'];
    $data=$data['chartData']['data'];
    /*print_r($data);*/

    echo 'TIME DATE  '.$date.'<br>';

    echo '<table style="width:100%"><tr><td>time stamp</td><td>data</td></tr>';
    foreach($data as $array) {
    echo '<tr><td>';
    print_r($array[0]);
    echo '</td><td>';
    print_r($array[1]);
    echo '</td></tr>';


            /*insert in db but you will have big quantity of queryes*/

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_power(date, data) VALUES('$array[0]',$array[1])";
            mysql_query($sql,$con);


    }
    echo '</table>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. How would this look in my code?

Comment: Thanks. I amended the code and loaded into my root folder to display in a web browser, but I still get an empty result set in mysql.

Comment: add insert in loop like i write but something is not good, to big number of query, may be you need to do one insert with all data  `insert into tbl(cell1,cell2,...celln-1,celln) values ('$data1','$data2',...,'$datan-1','$datan')

Comment: you have in the table `date, data1, data2` columns? may be sql error? Yon can see data in broser if remove sql insert from my code

Comment: and if `1457135400000` is time stamp when convert it to time and after echo

Comment: I have those 3 columns in the power table, but I get 404 error in browser without sql insert code. PHP settings? Or sql error based on table construction for type: I have data1 & data2 = text & date = date

Comment: I change code, you need  2 colums date and data, and try for begin type of string it together

Comment: Also I added example how to connect to DB. All work. After try to change type of columns to some type for store time stamp and data to float or other needed type

Comment: Amended, but still no luck in getting result in sql. Type for columns set to string>text. Collation set to utf8_unicode_ci. Running PHP 5.6.

Comment: I think you replace this `$bd_host, $bd_user, $bd_password, bd_name` with your. What error appear, if not inserted it will generate error message

Comment: Hi i try this answer but i have a error of because of a success response
{"success": true,"SalesData"} How can i ignore success reponse?